# How do I use a linq query to update the underlying database table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm using a strongly typed dataset and I will show my pseudo code below. What I'm trying to do is only select only one column value from the database because I believe this will make it faster and update the value if I need to and I have included my update method. What I'm not sure about is how to fill in the blanks and update the value so that it will update correctly.

```
var amexQuery = from c in amexTable
                where c.Date == date
                select new { adjustedClose = c.AdjustedClose };
```

// update the adjustedclose value here

```
tempAmexTable = (DailyAmexDataDataTable)amexTable.GetChanges();

                            if (tempAmexTable != null)
                            {
                                amexAdapter.Update(tempAmexTable);
                                tempAmexTable.Dispose();
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var amexQuery = (from c in amexTable
            where c.Date == date
            select c).FirstOrDefault();

amexQuery.AdjustedClose  = newValue
//call to Submit Changes to Update DB Change
```

Comment: I did something similar at first but I was trying to return only the adjusted close because I do this query thousands of times and I figured it would save on processing power if I only selected the only value I need to update. Is there a way to do that?